# decrease the time of script running (for loop based)

Tags: r, for-loop, optimization

I wrote a script based on two for loops that I would like to optimize to speed up its running time.

Below are reproducible data that I simplified with the code that I am using on my own data.

nuc is a vector with 101 "position" and
tel is a data frame with different coordinates "aa" and "bb"

The aim is to calculate for each position the number of times each position is comprised between each aa and bb coordinate. For example position 111 is comprise between 3 couple of coordinates : G, I and J

```
#data

tel=data.frame(aa=c(153,113,163,117,193,162,110,109,186,103),
               bb=c(189,176,185,130,200,189,156,123,198,189),
               ID=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"))

> tel
    aa  bb ID
1  153 189  A
2  113 176  B
3  163 185  C
4  117 130  D
5  193 200  E
6  162 189  F
7  110 156  G
8  109 123  H
9  186 198  I
10 103 189  J

nuc2=100:200

# Loop

count_occ=0
count_occ_int=NULL
count_occ_fin=NULL

for (j in 1:length(nuc2)){
  for (i in 1:nrow(tel)) {
    
    if (nuc2[j]< tel$bb[i] & nuc2[j]>tel$aa[i]) 
    {count_occ=count_occ+1}
  }
  count_occ_int=count_occ
  count_occ_fin=c(count_occ_fin,count_occ_int)
  count_occ=0
}

nuc_occ=data.frame(nuc=nuc2, occ=count_occ_fin)

> head(nuc_occ,20)
   nuc occ
1  100   0
2  101   0
3  102   0
4  103   0
5  104   1
6  105   1
7  106   1
8  107   1
9  108   1
10 109   1
11 110   2
12 111   3
13 112   3
14 113   3
15 114   4
16 115   4
17 116   4
18 117   4
19 118   5
20 119   5
```

In my data, the length of my nuc vector is 9304567 and the number of couple of coordinates is 53 (I will have some hundred soon) and it took more than 60 hours to run the code !!

Any idea to help me to speed up this code ?

I though to the apply function but I am not sure how to combine the two for loop operations.

Comment: Are you dead set on a loop?  Can we suggest other solutions?

Comment: You might see performance (big) performance gains if you initialize a vector of a fixed length and write directly to the relevant position, instead of copying and concatenating in each iteration.

Comment: @Limey I open to any other suggestion that a loop. I am always curious to see other solutions that mine as I am still a R beginner and I want to improve my knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use data.table non-equi join like this:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(tel)[SJ(v=nuc2), on=.(aa<=v, bb>=v)][,.(occ = sum(!is.na(ID))), by=.(nuc=aa)]
```

Explanation:

- `setDT(tel)` sets the `tel` data.frame to be of class data.table
- `SJ(v=nuc2)` is a convenience function for converting a vector to a data.table; in this case converting `nuc2` to a data.table with one column `v`. I'm doing this becuase I want to join two data.tables, one which is `tel` (with columns `aa`,`bb` and `v`) and one which has a single column `v` holding the values in `nuc2`
- the join conditions are in the `on=..` param of the `setDT(tel)[...]` clause; here the join condition is that the `v` value must be >= the `aa` value and must be <= the `bb` value
- the final step (i.e. the next chained data.table operation) simply counts the number of rows where ID is not NA, by `nuc` value (`by=.(nuc=aa)`)

Output:

```
       nuc   occ
     <int> <int>
  1:   100     0
  2:   101     0
  3:   102     0
  4:   103     1
  5:   104     1
 ---            
 97:   196     2
 98:   197     2
 99:   198     2
100:   199     1
101:   200     1
```

Comment: thank you for your solution. I will try it on my own data. Can you give me a bit of explanation of this command. I have difficulties to understand how it is working.

Comment: sure, have added an explanation.

Comment: Great thank you, it is much clearer now ! I tested it on my data and it reduce significantly the time of running ! Less than one hour (I did not look at it precisely) instead of more than 60 hours ! This is so cool !

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tidyverse solution:

```
lapply(
  100:200,
  \(x) tel %>% 
         filter(aa <= x & x <= bb) %>% 
         summarise(occ=n(), .groups="drop") %>% 
         add_column(nuc=x, .before=1)
) %>% 
bind_rows() %>% 
as_tibble()
# A tibble: 101 × 2
     nuc   occ
   <int> <int>
 1   100     0
 2   101     0
 3   102     0
 4   103     1
 5   104     1
 6   105     1
 7   106     1
 8   107     1
 9   108     1
10   109     2
# … with 91 more rows
```

Using `microbenchmark` to assess performance, this gives

```
Unit: nanoseconds
     expr min lq mean median uq max neval
   lapply   7  9  8.8      9  9   9    10
 original   8  9 23.8      9  9 158    10
```

In other words, a decrease in speed of about two-thirds.  And the tidyverse is not known for speed.  A base R solution is likely to be faster still.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I tried it but I have an error "Erreur : unexpected input in: "  100:200,  \"

Comment: @AureliaKurtis you can replace `\(x)` with `function(x)` if your R version <4.1